# Best way to implement Clone() in my specific classes

Tags: delphi, generics, clone, tpersistent

In my specific `TPersistent` classes I'd like to provide a `Clone` function, which returns an independent copy of the object.

Is it possible to make this work correctly with descendants, without implementing the `Clone` function in each and every descendant?

This is not about cloning any unknown fields or deep cloning (which could be done using RTTI). In my minimal example below, you can see where I would want to put the `Clone` function.

Since it uses `Assign()` to copy the data, it would work with any descendant. The problem is the constructor, see comments. How do I call the correct constructor of that descendant? If that's very hard to do, it's okay to assume that none of the descendants override the constructor without overriding `Clone`, too.

```
program Test;

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

type
  TMyClassBase = class abstract(TPersistent)
  public
    constructor Create; virtual; abstract;
    function Clone: TMyClassBase; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TMyClassBase<T> = class abstract(TMyClassBase)
  private
    FValue: T;
  public
    constructor Create; overload; override;
    function Clone: TMyClassBase; override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    property Value: T read FValue write FValue;
  end;

  TMyClassInt = class(TMyClassBase<Integer>)
  public
    function ToString: string; override;
  end;

  TMyClassStr = class(TMyClassBase<string>)
  public
    function ToString: string; override;
  end;

constructor TMyClassBase<T>.Create;
begin
  Writeln('some necessary initialization');
end;

procedure TMyClassBase<T>.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TMyClassBase<T> then FValue:= (Source as TMyClassBase<T>).FValue
  else inherited;
end;

function TMyClassBase<T>.Clone: TMyClassBase;
begin
  {the following works, but it calls TObject.Create!}
  Result:= ClassType.Create as TMyClassBase<T>;
  Result.Assign(Self);
end;

function TMyClassInt.ToString: string;
begin
  Result:= FValue.ToString;
end;

function TMyClassStr.ToString: string;
begin
  Result:= FValue;
end;

var
  ObjInt: TMyClassInt;
  ObjBase: TMyClassBase;
begin
  ObjInt:= TMyClassInt.Create;
  ObjInt.Value:= 42;
  ObjBase:= ObjInt.Clone;
  Writeln(ObjBase.ToString);
  Readln;
  ObjInt.Free;
  ObjBase.Free;
end.
```

The output is

```
some necessary initialization
42
```

So, the correct class came out, it works correctly in this minimal example, but unfortunately, my *necessary initialization* wasn't done (should appear twice).

I hope I could make it clear and you like my example code :) - I'd also appreciate any other comments or improvements. **Is my `Assign()` implementation ok?**

Comment: I would use `Result := TMyClassBase<T>.Create;`.

Comment: @Victoria, that wouldn't work, since the resulting object would be of type `TMyClassBase<T>` and not `TMyClassInt`, so it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make the non-generic base class constructor abstract. You can implement the clone there, because you have a virtual constructor.

Furthermore you don't need to make the `Clone` method virtual.

```
type
  TMyClassBase = class abstract(TPersistent)
  public
    constructor Create; virtual; abstract;
    function Clone: TMyClassBase; 
  end;

... 

type
  TMyClassBaseClass = class of TMyClassBase;

function TMyClassBase.Clone: TMyClassBase;
begin
  Result := TMyClassBaseClass(ClassType).Create;
  try
    Result.Assign(Self);
  except
    Result.DisposeOf;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Note that `ClassType` returns `TClass`. We cast it to `TMyClassBaseClass` to make sure that we call your base class virtual constructor.

I also don't see why you made `TMyClassBase<T>` abstract and derived specifications from it. You should be able to implement everything you need in the generic class.

Comment: @sertac Thank you

Comment: Great, that was what I was looking for - my understanding of the mechanics seems to be incomplete. I couldn't imagine that `TThis(TThat).Create` could return an object of TThat. Also the `class of` which you first forgot wasn't clear to me. However, maybe you want to edit your answer - you made it look like the solution is moving the Clone function to the base class, but that's not necessary. Better first explain the solution and move that as an additional recommendation into a postscript...

Comment: Since you can implement it in the base class you may as well. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: You are right and I will do so. I just think the first sentence shouldn't have the least important part of the solution. The solution I missed is the class-cast, that's the important part. Where I could put it better is additional info. Btw., is my `Assign` method good like it is?

Comment: You wrote "implement everything you need in the generic class": how would I do that? if..else for every possible type?

Comment: Put the value into a  `TValue` and call its ToString method. Any time you find yourself implementing a method in a specialisation it's a bad sign. Always try to avoid that.

Comment: `ToString` was just a simplified example. In real life my classes have to support exactly some few fixed types and cannot support all possible types. Of course you can always try to avoid it, but it's not automatically bad design. Let's say the output string has to be in quotes, the integer not. And even if it was exactly my example, wouldn't have the specialized `TMyClassStr.ToString` much better performance than feeding it through `TValue`?

Comment: Yes, but you also could not use `TMyClassBase<Integer>`, you'd have to use `TMyClassInt`, so you wouldn't be able to use these classes in a generic setting. If you want to specialise based on the type, within a generic method, use `GetTypeKind` and the like. This is all resolved at compile time too so you don't suffer any performance hits. Anyway, we are now drifting far from the question you asked, which I think has been answered.

Comment: @David you're welcome. A downvote made me realize the mistake and after a while I figured you'd call the day off..

Comment: The great thing is that we got a general solution and could put it into a reusable `TCloneable` class. Then every descendant from this class automatically becomes cloneable (if it implements the `Assign` method).
Note: when descendants need to introduce additional constructors, the developer has to take care that the parameterless `Create` + `Assign` still create a valid object. This pitfall might be the reason why there is no ready made `Clone`?

Answer (score -2):

This seems to do it:

```
function TMyClassBase<T>.Clone: TMyClassBase;
begin
  {create new instance using empty TObject constructor}
  Result:= ClassType.Create as TMyClassBase<T>;
  {execute correct virtual constructor of descendant on instance}
  Result.Create;
  {copy data to instance}
  Result.Assign(Self);
end;
```

However, I've never seen that before - it feels very, very wrong...

I verified that it correctly initializes data of the target object and really calls the descendants constructor *once*. I see no problem, there is also no memory leak reported. Tested using Delphi 10.2.2. Please comment :)

Comment: You seem to call the constructor twice

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that would result in a memory leak, isn't it? But it doesn't. Actions of the second .Create go to the existing object. I can imagine good reasons to downvote this, but this reason is just not true. You can easily copy my whole example and try it out. How many "some necessary initialization" do you see?

Comment: Have your constructor create an object owned by the class. Destroy it in the destructor. Then you'll see a leak.

Comment: The second Create call is on an instance, hence it operates on that instance and does not create yet another instance. [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Constructors).

Comment: OK, I guess you get away with it because you first call TObject.Create which does nothing. But still, you may as well instantiate with the virtual constructor

Comment: Interesting: my working and tested solution gets downvotes and even a delete request (why?!), while a wrong solution gets edited (not by the author) to become working :) never mind. This answer was never meant to be a real solution, I knew there was a correct one. I just think, it's still interesting and should stay for educational purposes... @DavidHeffernan

Comment: There's a difference between getting the concept right, but messing up the code, as I did, and getting the code right but for the wrong concept, as you did. Yes this might work but isn't it best to do it right? Hence the voting.

Comment: I'd still be interested in deeper info or more links, @SertacAkyuz link was already very interesting. I.e. one thing I'm still wondering about: how is the correct size of the new memory determined, when only the `TObject` constructor is called here?

Comment: Because the class reference that you pass is `ClassType` which is the class of `Self`